# Filling gaps in a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table (say Table A) with three columns of the form. Just to make sure that we is workweek column and each year rolls into 01 work week after we 52:

```
 PN      SP      Pr      WW
 -----------------------------
 P1      S1      300    202301            
 P1      S1      400    202305        
 P1      S3      600    202302   
 P1      S3      700    202305
 P2      S3      700    202301   
 P2      S3      800    202306
```

What I want to do is to plug in values from Pr Column  for gaps in WW column from  the last available prev WW value up to the next WW value based on the  grouping from the PN & SP column. So the final table (say Table B) should  look like as follows: in this case since there are gaps from 202302 to 202304 for p1 & s1 we fill by the value from 202301, for p1 and & s3 gap from 202303 to 202304, we fill by the value of p3 and s3 combination in 202302 and so on

```
 PN      SP      Pr      WW
 -----------------------------
 P1      S1      300    202301 
 P1      S1      300    202302
 P1      S1      300    202303  
 P1      S1      300    202304   
 P1      S1      400    202305        
 P1      S3      600    202302
 P1      S3      600    202303 
 P1      S3      600    202304  
 P1      S3      700    202305
 P2      S3      700    202301
 P2      S3      700    202302 
 P2      S3      700    202303 
 P2      S3      700    202304 
 P2      S3      700    202305   
 P2      S3      800    202306
```

What will the SQL query to get the  Table B from table A?

Thanks

Comment: Have you even tried anything? Do you have a Calendar table? What have you researched?

Comment: I had created using a CTE along with recursion, but is not working.. WITH RankedData AS (
    SELECT 
        PN, SP, Pr, WW,
        LEAD(WW, 1, 999999) OVER (PARTITION BY PN, SP ORDER BY WW) AS NextWW
    FROM TableA
),
GapFilled AS (
    SELECT 
        a.PN, a.SP, a.Pr, a.WW
    FROM RankedData a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        a.PN, a.SP, a.Pr, a.WW + 1
    FROM GapFilled a
    INNER JOIN RankedData b ON a.PN = b.PN AND a.SP = b.SP
    WHERE a.WW + 1 < b.NextWW
)
SELECT * FROM GapFilled
ORDER BY PN, SP, WW
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

Comment: [edit] any clarifications directly into your question

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for the output that you desire. I think it can be done in a better way, but I've found this solution

```
WITH calendarDate AS (
-- create a calendar table

    SELECT MIN(WW) AS date
    FROM ProductData
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cd.date + 1
    FROM calendarDate cd
    JOIN ProductData p ON cd.date < p.WW

), distinctDate as ( 
-- just get the unique dates

    SELECT DISTINCT date
    FROM calendarDate

), distinctProduct AS (

-- get the distinct combination of pn and sp

    SELECT DISTINCT pn, sp 
    FROM ProductData

), crossDates as (

-- cross tables between distinctProduct and distinctDate and then use left join with productData. 
-- I use an indicator for just filter between dates that I need 

    SELECT 
        dp.PN,
        dp.SP,
        D.date,
        PD.pr,
        CASE WHEN Pr IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END indicator
    FROM distinctProduct dp
    CROSS JOIN distinctDate d
    LEFT JOIN ProductData pd
    ON dp.PN = pd.PN and dp.SP = pd.SP and d.date = pd.WW

), cumCte as (
    -- cumsum of indicator for future filter
    select 
        *, 
        SUM(indicator) OVER(PARTITION BY pn, sp ORDER BY date) cum
    from crossDates
)

-- final output
select 
    PN,
    SP,
    case when pr is not null then pr
    else first_value(pr) over(partition by pn, sp order by date)
    end WW,
    date as PR
from cumCte
where cum <> 0 and (cum - indicator) <= 1
order by pn, sp, date
```

Comment: "SELECT cd.date + 1" will not work if you have WW in different years: you will generate rows with weeks > 52.

Comment: ok, what solution do you have to make a calendar table?

Comment: You have to convert YYYYWW into a DATE with an UDF, so you will need to know if WW is the ISO week or not and instead of adding 1 you need to add 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

Use recursive CTE to generate list of work weeks and then use window function `lead()` to get the next workweek. With that, left join your tableA to the workweek cte

```
with 
workweek as -- recursive CTE to generate list of workweek
(
  select ww = 202301
  union all
  select ww = ww + 1
  from   workweek
  where  ww < 202352
),
cte as
(
 select *, nextWW = lead(WW) over (partition by PN, SP order by WW)
  from   tableA a
)
select c.PN, c.SP, c.PR, WW = coalesce(ww.WW, c.WW)
from   cte c
       left join workweek ww on  ww.ww >= c.WW
                             and ww.ww <  c.nextWW
order by c.PN, c.SP, c.PR, WW
```